# SMTP setup failed

Tags: php, smtp

I am developing the a form, which sends a mail to a specified address. But the its not working. The response is

> Warning: mail(): SMTP server response:
>   421-4.7.0 [39.47.24.63 15] Our system has detected an unusual rate of
>   421-4.7.0 unsolicited mail originating from your IP address. To protect our
>   421-4.7.0 users from spam, mail sent from your IP address has been temporarily
>   421-4.7.0 rate limited. Please visit
>   421-4.7.0 http://www.google.com/mail/help/bulk_mail.html to review our Bulk
>   421 4.7.0 Email Senders Guidelines.
>   b2si11588888wiz.64 - gsmtp in C:\xampp\htdocs\mail\backend.php on line 20

And line no 20 is given as:

```
ini_set('SMTP', 'aspmx.l.google.com');
```

What should I do to overcome the problem?

Comment: Have you followed the instructions it gave you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically an automated system put into place at the google mail server side is stopping you from sending this mail because you have sent a lot already, I would suggest to overcome the problem you no longer send this forward to google.

You can try doing exactly what the error told you to do? "Please visit 421-4.7.0 http://www.google.com/mail/help/bulk_mail.html to review our Bulk 421 4.7.0 Email Senders Guidelines" which should clear up how to avoid this problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It seems while testing you have tried to send one too many email,

try to wait a little and send less emails

It says that you sent too many emails to lot of email addresses, emails to email addresses you did not opt to receive them